python django floadformat doesn't work with arabic langauge
I am working on an ecomerece site, In django template i want to render value with float value 2 like that
{{product.tax_price|floatformat:2}}

it return correct value when language in english as soon as i change into arabic it render value
like 120,00 instead of 120.00.
can you please specify the issue i am having thanks in advance
I have try syntax describe in django formating documentation
    {{ product.tax_price|floatformat:"3u" }}    


You need to activate English then in  the view.

i am taking language every time when some view is called it can be changed any time in website

Did you check data typr before put in render??
Like this
product.tax_price = Decimal(product.tax_price).quantize(Decimal('0.00'))

and pass it like parem.

This value is coming from API and we need to add .00 at the end of value using django templating. this issue arises due to the decimal and thousand operators are changed in certain countries

This issue arises due to different decimal and thousand operators in different countries.
After trying many solutions,I came to know that
 {{ product.tax_price|floatformat:2u }}

is working in every language.
